# How to filter based on the different criteria and merge 2 datasets in power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 power query advance editor code.

Query_1

```
    let
    Source = ABC
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows( SAPS4, each [FiscalYearPeriod] <> "2023011" and [FiscalYearPeriod] <> "2023012" and not Text.StartsWith([FiscalYearPeriod], "2023013"))
    Some other steps =....
    in 
    Some other steps
```

Query_2

```
    let
    Source = ABC
    Filter Rows =  Table.SelectRows( SAPS4, each [FiscalYearPeriod] <> "2023011" and [FiscalYearPeriod] <> "2023012" and not Text.StartsWith([FiscalYearPeriod], "2023013"))
    in 
    Filter Rows
```

What I would like to do writing both queries into 1 query then combine them. Is there a way to do that ? many thanks in advance

Comment: Not if you expect to have two different output tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give the requested result:

```
let
    Tbl1 =
        let
            Source = ABC
            #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows( SAPS4, each [FiscalYearPeriod] <> "2023011" and [FiscalYearPeriod] <> "2023012" and not Text.StartsWith([FiscalYearPeriod], "2023013"))
            Some other steps =....
        in 
            Some other steps,
    Tbl2 =
        let
            Source = ABC
            Filter Rows =  Table.SelectRows( SAPS4, each [FiscalYearPeriod] <> "2023011" and [FiscalYearPeriod] <> "2023012" and not Text.StartsWith([FiscalYearPeriod], "2023013"))
        in 
            Filter Rows,
            
    Append = Table.Combine({Tbl1,Tbl2})
in 
    Append
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tables have identical columns, you can append them. If they have a common column/key, you can merge them into one table